# Copying lists: editing copy without changing original

Tags: python, arrays

I'm making a program that requires and editable temp array that does not affect the original. However, whenever I run the function and test it, it edits the actual array like so:

```
x = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
y = copying(x)
y[0][0] = 1
print(x)
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Here is the function:

```
def copying(array):
    temp = []

    for i in array:
        temp.append(i)        
    return temp
```

The function works for flat lists, but the array entry doesn't work. Is there an alternative that I should use? (I have attempted list() and copy())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [function `deepcopy` from `copy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

> `copy.deepcopy(x)`
>
> Return a deep copy of x.

This function is copying everything, even sub elements (and sub sub elements and... you understand I think). Your short example corrected:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> x = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> y = deepcopy(x)
>>> y[0][0] = 1
>>> x
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> y
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```